# Create TextView ( in the code ) with style but without attributes

Tags: java, android

Howdy,
I am currently generating some textviews in a loop. It would be great if I could apply a style to those textviews.

This style already containts all attributes so I would not neet to set a Attribute, however if I do this

`TextView counterTV = new TextView(activity,null, R.style.MenuField);`

the TextView is created but there is are no styles applied to it :(.

It works flawlessly if I apply the same style to a textview in a XML File.

Answer (score 3):

Try this little beauty:

```
TextView counterTV = new TextView(activity);
counterTV.setTextAppearance(activity, R.style.MenuField);
```

I have used it to apply the standard Android styles (like `android.R.style.TextAppearance_Large`) to `TextView`s before.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the Layout Params?